# Can't reproduce the tutorial example "Scrumptious " in Facebook iOS SDK 3.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api, xcode4.3, facebook-ios-sdk

I followed instructions of [Facebook SDK for iOS Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/) and tried to reproduce my own project which resembles the "Scrumptious" example(Sample project in the SDK)

The odd thing is, after authenticating the user in FB login, the user is locked in the FB section and can't ever return to the app. The code is same with "Scrumptious" but "Scrumptious" worked just fine. Any suggestion?

(I did updated Open Graph namespaces, using heroku as hosted service and add a Tester user in my facebook app. The Readme.txt in the sample project said that this is essential for posting Open Graph Actions.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you properly register the callback url in your info.plist?  See the last steps in the instructions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/getting-started-with-the-ios-sdk/#project